# Extend image by viewpoint beyond DIV container

Tags: javascript, view, width

I have a black rectangle I wish to extend the full left to right horizontal viewpoint. Problem is, I have a DIV container (980px) I can't change (long story - basically restriction of the software I'm using).

```
style="position:fixed; left:0%; width:100%; height:300px"
```

This works, but I'm left with a fixed rectangle I don't want. Absolute positioning extends to a maximum of 980px (governing DIV container). Any suggestions? JS?

Any information you can provide would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your stylesheet you will need to change the parent div ( the 980px div ) to have position: static

```
#parentDiv{
    width:960px;
    position:static;
}

#fullWidth{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background: #000;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you realseanp. I'll see if I can update the parent div, though it might not be possible given application restrictions.

Comment: Yes!!! It worked. This has taken me over a year to work out. Thank you so much realseanp!!!

Comment: Glad that worked! You should accept this as the answer so I get the points

Comment: So sorry about that. Still getting the hang of this website.